# Docker container , sbt not found

Tags: java, docker, playframework, dockerfile, sbt

I have a ubuntu server and thats my docker file:

```
FROM openjdk:11
WORKDIR /testimaje
COPY /play-samples-play-java-hello-world-tutorial .
EXPOSE 9000
CMD sbt run
```

When I want make container from this file I am getting `/bin/sh: l sbt:not found`

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues here:

- you'd need to install SBT in the container to be able to run `sbt run` when it starts. You can do this by adding instructions to install SBT in the Dockerfile, or use a base image that contains SBT already.
- unless it's for test/development purposes, you don't want to run your app through SBT: you package it thanks to SBT which gives you a bunch of JAR typically and you run `java -jar ...` to run your app.

  - you mentioned Play Framework in your tags, running `sbt stage` will generate a bash script that you can use as-is to run your app